# Concat a string based on condition in oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle

I want to concat to the output based on condition. Here is my query:

```
select 'hey',
  case id =1 then 'Mary' else 'Tom' end 
from names;'
```

I want to print 'hey tom' or 'hey mary' based on id ... any help ??

Answer (score 3):

It is **concatenation** you need; in Oracle, double pipe `||` represents that operator:

```
SQL> with names (id) as
  2    (select 1 from dual union all
  3     select 2 from dual union all
  4     select 3 from dual
  5    )
  6  select id,
  7    'hey ' || case when id = 1 then 'Mary'
  8                   else 'Tom'
  9              end result
 10  from names;

        ID RESULT
---------- ----------
         1 hey Mary
         2 hey Tom
         3 hey Tom

SQL>
```

Comment: That's what you say. I say that it works. If you provided test case (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements), I wouldn't have to to create my own. What you need is lines #6 onward.

Comment: `dual` is a built-in Oracle table that's frequently used for generating sample data. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries009.htm

Comment: @yarabyarab: [it works perfectly](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fd1d1d20442e0a8619f6ad37372fff3d)

Answer (score 0):

You can run something like this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('hey ', FIRST_NAME) from names where ID = '1';
```